# C# Change label depending of ComboBox Selected Index

Tags: c#, combobox, selectedindexchanged

I want to display certain value into a label depending of the item selected in the comboBox, each item in the comboBox will display a different value, problem is the comboBox has a lot of items and each one needs to display a different value

```
private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   switch (comboBox.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    Label.Text = "8";
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    Label.Text = "15";
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    Label.Text = "60";
                }
                break;
         }
}
```

How can I improve this and do it shorter? I was told to use an object array but how to verify which item is selected?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of using List to make your code shorter:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IList<string> lstString = new List<string>();
        lstString.Add("Hello");
        lstString.Add("World");
        lstString.Add("Foo");
        lstString.Add("C#");
        lstString.Add("StackOverflow");
        label1.Text = lstString[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
    }
```

Since list starts at index zero and combobox starts at index zero, you can just call the index of the list to match with the index of your combobox.

Comment: Thank you! this kind of list is what I needed but I couldn't figure it out by myself

Comment: You are welcome! You can now accept it as an answer for reference to other programmers as well. @RobertoMTorres

Answer (score 0):

You can do an initialization of your combobox.(put it on `load` event of form or somewhere else depends on your needs.)

```
var listCombo = new List<int>();
listCombo.Add(8);
listCombo.Add(15);
listCombo.Add(60);
listCombo.ForEach(m =>  comboBox1.Items.Add(m.ToString()));
```

Then you can just assign the selected item in the label in the event code of combobox

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     label1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

[image]